# Send values to previous activity where those values are to be displayed in table

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity from which I want to **navigate to another activity** on a **button click** event.

Now in newly opened activity I have some edittext fields and a button. On clicking button I want to **send values** of **edittext** to **previous activity** where I want to show them in a table dynamically.

Please guide me how to do it.

Comment: Use onActivityResult...

Answer (score 1):

In button in Activity_A put this

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity_A.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

Then Override onActivityResult(...)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                 int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 100){
         String editBoxTxt = data.getExtras().getString("txt");

         Toast.makeText(this,editBoxTxt  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
    }

}
```

And in Activity_B

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Activity_A.class);
            // String str = get EditText value
            in.putExtra("txt", str);
            setResult(100, in);
            // Closing Activity_B
            finish();
```

Hope this helped you.

Comment: Actually i am getting value back in previous activity but I want to display them in TableLayout dynamically. so if you could guide me ?

Comment: See this link [--Android User Interface Design: Table Layouts--](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_table-layout/).